# Select database values from textbox

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have one listbox with 'firstname' and 'lastname' stored in it from the database.

How do i write my query to retrieve information from the database selecting the index.

I have

```
"Select * from table where firstname= '"+listbox1.Text+"' and lastname= '"+listbox1.Text+"' "
```

Dont work though

Comment: Could you clarify your question, please. The first name and last name are in your `listbox` and are sourced from the database, but some details would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

What you have looks like a good start aside from the SQL Injection vulnerability.  I would read up on parameterized queries.  [This is an article](http://forums.asp.net/t/1568268.aspx) that I feel goes over the concept well.

You will end up using a combination of SqlConnection, SqlCommand, SqlParameter and probably a few other classes.

Answer (score 1):

Two words (two ways): `Parameterized Queries` or `Prepared Statements`. What you call it depends on which you prefer - they mean the same exact thing! There are performance and security benefits from using them.

I'm assuming by what I've read in your question that this is what you have. Where your `listbox` control just contains a list of names that are found in your database which are just contained as `Items` in your `listbox`.

[image: My interpretation]

This is not an advisable design, but lets  make it function without a rework of what you already have.

For `SQL Server` and `C#`, the code would be like this:

```
string commandText = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE firstname = @firstname and lastname = @lastname";
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
    if (listbox1.SelectedItem == null)
    {
         // exit since nothing was selected in the listbox to query by
    }
    var names = listbox1.SelectedItem.ToString().Split(' ');
    if (names.Length != 2)
    {
         // exit since this is not what we want and will yield unexpected results
    }
    string firstName = names[0];
    string lastName = names[1];
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", firstname);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", lastname);

    // Read information from database...

}
```

Obviously you can see why this is not an advisable design choice, but it will work given what you already have set up.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a "where" when using LINQ to SQL...

```
<asp:LinqDataSource 
            ContextTypeName="YourDataContext" 
            TableName="YourTable" 
            ID="DataSource" 
            runat="server"
            Where="FirstName == @FN">
            <WhereParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter Name="FN" ControlID="LISTBOX"
                                      Type="String" PropertyName="Text" />
            </WhereParameters>
</asp:LinqDataSource>
```